# Interfacing with an Abstract Class of Different Derived Class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, abstract-class

I have four classes and an interface, something like this:

```
public interface ISource
{
     DesiredFunc();
}

public class Source
{

}

public class SourceA : Source
{

}

public class SourceAChild : SourceA, ISource
{
     DesiredFunc()
     {
     }
}

public abstract class SourceB : Source, ISource
{
     DesiredFunc()
     {
     }
}
```

`Source` and `SourceA` come from a library so there's no way I can change their implementation.  There is a `SourceAChild` object which calls `DesiredFunc()` but it needs to use the implementation of `DesiredFunc()` in `SourceB`.

What I have done so far is create a wrapper class of `SourceB`.  I create an instance of that class inside of `SourceAChild` and then call the base method. Something like

```
public class SourceBChild : SourceB, ISource
{
    DesiredFunc()
     {
          base.DesiredFunc();
     }
}

public class SourceAChild : SourceA, ISource
{
    SourceBChild srcB = new SourceBChild();

     DesiredFunc()
     {
         srcB.DesiredFunc();
     }
}
```

This seems pretty ugly to me.  Is there a better way to get to `SourceB's` implementation of `DesiredFunc()`?  One of the biggest problems I can see with the workaround I currently have is data integrity between `SourceAChild` and `SourceBChild` because the former class updates its properties frequently.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe you can look into implementing a Decorator pattern?

Comment: Is `SourceB` something you created, or is this from the same library as `SourceA`?

Comment: Well *I* didn't create `SourceB`.  It is something that can be modified although I was advised not to if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To call a non-static method of an abstract class, you always need a class instance, and so you will have to subclass it.

If `DesiredFunc` of `SourceB` is `public`, your wrapper class can be simplified to:

```
public class SourceBChild : SourceB
{
}
```

The `DesiredFunc` method will then automatically be exposed. However if it's `protected`, you'll need to wrap it as you already did.

The last line of your comments doesn't make much sense to me - you mention data integrity and properties, but since `DesiredFunc` of `SourceB` runs on an instance of `SourceBChild`, it can't use the fields or properties of your `SourceA` instance.

Comment: `DesiredFunc` is protected so I guess I'm stuck.  What I meant by data integrity is that this `DesiredFunc` works on a property buried deep in the parent `Source` class which displays some info to the user.  My concern is that when `SourceB` calls that function, what is shown to the user might not necessarily agree with what is stored in `SourceAChild` as it should.